# c# - AspNetCore set content root path

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor

How can I change `Content root path` on app .Net Core 3.0 ASP Blazor start?
Now app starts with output

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\Art\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
!!! C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\6c2bb0ad-5956-4886-9e3f-2135ebe50d2f_1.0.8.0_x64__n37t8n8dtxdg6\TUTDF_Viewer_v2\
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Windows\system32
```

I need to change `Content root path` from `C:\Windows\system32` to another path on app initialization.

How to change `Content root path` on AspNetCore app start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most correct way is to change Program.cs of the project - to add

```
var p = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
                    p = p.Substring(0, p.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1);
webBuilder.UseContentRoot(p);
```

in `CreateHostBuilder`.

Full example:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    var p = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
                    p = p.Substring(0, p.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1);

                    webBuilder.UseContentRoot(p);
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for an ASP.NET Core MVC v3.1 project. The solution for us was just to change current directory to the webapp directory and start the .dll from there with dotnet

Answer (score 1):

Please use below code

```
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string pathToContentRoot = string.Empty;

        var pathToExe = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
        pathToContentRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToExe);
        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(pathToContentRoot);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Directory.SetCurrentDirectory only works for loading razor content and config.

If you have static files (UseStaticFiles) as middleware active,
you must have somewhere this too.

```
           env.ContentRootPath = pathToContentRoot;
```

Answer (score 0):

on ASP7 we inserted following code to make it work into `program.cs`

```
WebApplicationOptions options = new WebApplicationOptions {
    ContentRootPath = "/var/www/yourpath"
};
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(options);
```